# How do it scrape text from website using urllib and BeautifulSoup? I cannot get the text following the 'b' tag

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I cannot get the text following the 'b' tag. It just gives me the following OP
for : b_tag[10].text
'                                     YOUNG WOMAN\r\n'

'''

```
import urllib.request as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://imsdb.com/scripts/Pulp-Fiction.html'

htmlfile=ureq.urlopen(url)

htmltext=htmlfile.read()

htmlfile.close()

html_soup = bs(htmltext,'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

html_soup.body
b_tag = html_soup.findAll('b')
b_tag[0].text
```

'''

Comment: What is expected output? The whole script text?

Answer (score 0):

Try theses:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get( 'https://imsdb.com/scripts/Pulp-Fiction.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
tra = soup.find('b').text.strip()
print(tra)
```

Comment: output:  `PULP FICTION`

Comment: it is `work` for you??

Comment: if answer is correct kindly tick the answer

Comment: Nope, did not work :(